# Is there a way to combine two UI elements?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel

I am developing a mobile app in Swift and I have a custom `UIView` that displays a circular progress bar, but I want to add a `UILabel` in the middle that also displays the progress percentage. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How did you implement your custom progress view? Update your question with relevant code. Did you try adding a label as a subview? Or rendering the text in `drawRect:`?

Answer (score 1):

UIViews can overlap. You can just put the label on top of your custom view, or you can make the label a subview of your custom view.

Comment: What exactly would making the label a subview do? And how would that be implemented?

Comment: These are very basic questions. It sounds like you need to read [“Creating and Managing a View Hierarchy” in the *View Programming Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW47).